# How to access and assign a string value as a string name dynamically in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, variable-assignment

In PHP I can dynamically access a variable by setting something like `$variable_name = foo` and `echo $$variable_name` which would then `echo` the value of `foo`. But I am unclear on how to do this in Ruby. In PHP I could do something like this; assign variable names in an array and iterate through them:

```
# Set string values.
$value_one = 'a one';
$value_two = 'and a two';
$value_three = 'and a three';

# Set array of variable names.
$process_items_array = array('value_one', 'value_two', 'value_three');

# Roll through the values.
foreach ($process_items_array as $value) {
  $$value = do_something($$value) . '<br />';
}

# A simple function for example’s sake.
function do_something ($value = null) {
  return strtoupper($value);
}
```

But in Ruby, what would be the equivalent? For example I have tried this and none of the items work as expected; note that is this psuedo-code as noted by the use of `self.` references in a non-class structure:

```
# Set string values.
value_one = 'a one';
value_two = 'and a two';
value_three = 'and a three';

# Set array of variable names.
process_items_array = ['value_one', 'value_two', 'value_three']

# Roll through the values.
process_items_array.each { |value|
  self.send("#{value}").to_sym = do_something value.try(self.send("#{value}").to_sym)
}

# A simple function for example’s sake.
def do_something value
  value = value.try(:strip)
  value = nil if value.blank?
  value.upcase
end
```

Note my attempted use of [`instance_variable_get`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get), [`send][2]` and [`to_sym`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/String.html#method-i-to_sym); I’m basically hoping something will work but nothing seems to work. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: I'm sure what you're using this for, but it doesn't seem like something that one should be doing in Ruby - there's probably a more robust way to do it with a wee bit of redesigning.

Comment: This is what dictionaries and hash maps were invented for - to refer to a value by another (changeable) key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with [`eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Kernel.html#method-i-eval):

```
# Set string values.
value_one = 'a one';
value_two = 'and a two';
value_three = 'and a three';

# Set array of variable names.
process_items_array = ['value_one', 'value_two', 'value_three']

# Roll through the values.
process_items_array.each do |variable_name|

  # Output value
  puts eval(variable_name)

  # Reassign variable
  new_value = 'foo'
  eval("#{variable_name} = new_value")
end
```

As it was said in the comments, you might want to store your data within a Hash. Also, code where  you need to dynamically create or read variables smells really bad.

Comment: Eval simply returns you value retuned by the ruby code in question, I will update my answer in a minute

Comment: @JakeGould done, just wanted to make clear to you what eval does

Comment: @JakeGould glad to help, hope you'll fall in love with Ruby =)

Comment: There is no reason to use [`Kernel#eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) here, please use [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) and [`Binding#local_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set) instead, that's what they're there for.

Comment: See [@jag's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27886560/2988) for how to use [`Kernel#binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-binding) and [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) and [`Binding#local_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set).

Answer (score 1):

A more ruby way (so without the "dangerous" eval)

```
# Set string values.
value_one = 'a one';
value_two = 'and a two';
value_three = 'and a three';

# Set array of variable names.
process_items_array = ['value_one', 'value_two', 'value_three']

# Roll through the values.
process_items_array.each do |variable_name|

  # Output value
  puts binding.local_variable_get(variable_name.to_sym)

  # Reassign variable
  binding.local_variable_set(variable_name.to_sym, 'foo')
end

puts value_one, value_two, value_three
# foo
# foo
# foo
```

Comment: unfortunately binding is available only in ruby 2.1 and later

Comment: I have posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27891195/2988) showing how to call a method for your convenience.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`Kernel#binding`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-binding) to get the current `Binding` object and then [`Binding#local_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get) and [`Binding#local_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_set) to get and set the local variables:

```
# Set string values.
value_one = 'a one';
value_two = 'and a two';
value_three = 'and a three';

# Set array of variable names.
process_items_array = ['value_one', 'value_two', 'value_three']

# Roll through the values.
process_items_array.each { |value|
  binding.local_variable_set(value.to_sym, do_something(binding.local_variable_get(value).to_sym)
}

# A simple function for example’s sake.
def do_something value
  value = value.try(:strip)
  value = nil if value.blank?
  value.upcase
end

# Show that it works:
p value_one, value_two, value_three
# "A ONE"
# "AND A TWO"
# "AND A THREE"
```

However, that code is a bit unidiomatic:

- You wouldn't use *both* semicolons and newlines as an expression separator, only one
- You would use `Symbol`s for representing the variable names, not `String`s
- You would use `do`/`end` instead of `{`/`}` for a multiline side-effecting block
- You wouldn't state the type of the object referenced by a variable in the variable name (e.g. `foo_array`)

You would also have to move the definition of `do_something` up before it is used, otherwise you get a `NoMethodError`.

And for easier reproducibility, I removed the dependency on the `active_support`, so that people trying to test this don't have to install an extra gem which isn't even needed to reproduce the solution.

This would be a more idiomatic version of the code:

```
# Set string values.
value_one =   'a one'
value_two =   'and a two'
value_three = 'and a three'

# Set array of variable names.
items_to_process = %i[value_one value_two value_three]

# A simple method for example’s sake.
def do_something(value)
  value.upcase
end

b = binding

# Roll through the values.
items_to_process.each do |var|
  b.local_variable_set(var, do_something(b.local_variable_get(var)))
end

# Show that it works:
p value_one, value_two, value_three
# "A ONE"
# "AND A TWO"
# "AND A THREE"
```